# Ruby - access parent property from child - one to many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class PriceList < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :prices, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

and Price:

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :price_list
  belongs_to :material
  belongs_to :unit
end
```

Now in price_list index I want to show Price list name instead of id:

```
<tbody>
    <% @prices.each do |price| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= price.price_list.price_list_short_name %></td>
        <td><%= price.materials_id %></td>
        <td><%= price.units_id %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', price %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_price_path(price) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', price, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

What I am doing wrong that `price.price_list.price_list_short_name` does not work?

Comment: What error do you get? Can you add in the `price_list_short_name` method please.

Comment: Do you have `price_list_short_name `  in `PriceList` can you show us exception?

Comment: In what column do you store price_list's name?

Comment: I have undefined method price_list_short_name' for nil:NilClass error. price_list_short_name is a field in database model, so do not have any method. I simply want to access database property.

Comment: I have my price_list name in price_list_short_name column of price_lists table

Answer (score 1):

At least one of your `Price` records doesn't have its `price_list` associated. The solution depends on your intentions. If you want to force all `prices` to have `price_list`, you can add validation:

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :price_list, presence: true
  # ...
end
```

If you want to allow price_list-less `prices`, you could make use of `try` method, which will fix the error in view:

```
price.price_list.try(:price_list_short_name)
```

BTW, naming your column `price_list_short_name` in `price_lists` table is a bit redundant.

Comment: `price.materials_id` shows that that every record has price_list associated. Also checked this in database. `price.price_list.try(:price_list_short_name)`shows nothing. wil try to change column name from price_list_short_name to short_name. Maybe this is causing problems?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing proper references.
Adding to migration file:

```
class AddReferencesToPrices < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :prices, :price_list_id
    remove_column :prices, :materials_id
    remove_column :prices, :units_id
    add_reference :prices, :price_list, :index => true
    add_reference :prices, :material, :index => true
    add_reference :prices, :unit, :index => true
  end
end
```

solved problem.